# Cordova Missing Assets Contents

Tags: android, cordova

I am having trouble using *cordova build android*

It appears the assets folder is empty:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'mydirectory\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\cordova_plugins.js

When I got to this directory I find the assets folder but there is no www folder and it is empty. I'm not sure why, it used to have everything in it before. *cordova clean* builds but it does not solve the error when I proceed to *cordova build android*

Advice is appreciated!

Comment: Hello, I am also facing this problem.. Have you found a solution, thanks! ?